# Call a POST using POSTMAN

Tags: html, web-services, post, postman

I have an exam and i need to utilize the web method. Please see the link below

**https://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx?op=CelsiusToFahrenheit**

I don't know if I'm doing it right.

I don't know which to call. So i inspect element the page

And i found this

```
<form target="_blank" action="http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx/CelsiusToFahrenheit" method="POST">                      

                          <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="4" frame="box" bordercolor="#dcdcdc" rules="none" style="border-collapse: collapse;">
                          <tbody><tr>
    <td class="frmHeader" background="#dcdcdc" style="border-right: 2px solid white;">Parameter</td>
    <td class="frmHeader" background="#dcdcdc">Value</td>
</tr>


                          <tr>
                            <td class="frmText" style="color: #000000; font-weight: normal;">Celsius:</td>
                            <td><input class="frmInput" type="text" size="50" name="Celsius"></td>
                          </tr>

                        <tr>
                          <td></td>
                          <td align="right"> <input type="submit" value="Invoke" class="button"></td>
                        </tr>
                        </tbody></table>


                    </form>
```

So i called the `http://www.w3schools.com/xml/tempconvert.asmx/CelsiusToFahrenheit` 
I tried using POSTMAN

[image]

But the result is

```
404 Not Found
```

It's the same when i paste 50 in the form. And click the button in the HTML

```
404 - Page not found
```

My question is am i doing it correctly. I'm really confused right now. If what am i doing is correct. And if not what is the correct way of doing this

Comment: The endpoint expects `Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded` but still I tested the endpoint out and looks like the server side implementation is broken.

Answer (score 0):

If their own example is not working maybe the API is not working or is removed. You can't realy do much about it in my opinion

Answer (score 0):

After checking the specs of the API what I can see is you have to call via urlencoded not via raw. , but still i believe the API is no longer working

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/61mub.png)

Comment: Please click on the image link you will get the sample of calling such APIs